# JQuery Datepicker not displaying the theme correctly

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using the [jQuery UI 1.11.4](http://jqueryui.com/download/all/) with the [Sunny theme](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#!zThemeParams=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). Here is an example of what the date picker should look like:

[image: Datepicker Sunny theme example]

Because I don't want to change the current style of the website, I am using CSS Scope when I download the theme. Below is the code I am using in the page:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/scripts/custom/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/scripts/custom/jquery-ui.theme.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= txtSepDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            maxDate: "+0D",
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "/images/calendar.jpg",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonText: "Select date",
            beforeShow: function () {
                $(this).datepicker("widget").addClass("grace");
            },
            onClose: function () {
                $(this).datepicker("widget").removeClass("grace");
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my result when the page is accessed:

[image: My output of the date picker]

My resulting output compared to example is missing a few UI clues.

- The week day text
- The calendar border
- The calendar background

What am I going incorrectly?

Answer (score -1):

here is demo for datepicker calender

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/themeroller.css"/>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
<style>
   
.ui-widget {
    font-family: Segoe UI,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
.ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-size: 1em;
}
.ui-widget input, .ui-widget select, .ui-widget textarea, .ui-widget button {
    font-family: Segoe UI,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.ui-widget-content {
    background: #feeebd url("/themeroller/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_feeebd_1x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% top;
    border: 1px solid #8e846b;
    color: #383838;
}
.ui-widget-content a {
    color: #383838;
}
.ui-widget-header {
    background: #817865 url("/themeroller/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_45_817865_500x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50%;
    border: 1px solid #494437;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.ui-widget-header a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    background: #fece2f url("/themeroller/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_60_fece2f_500x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50%;
    border: 1px solid #d19405;
    color: #4c3000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.ui-state-default a, .ui-state-default a:link, .ui-state-default a:visited {
    color: #4c3000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
    background: #ffdd57 url("/themeroller/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_70_ffdd57_500x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50%;
    border: 1px solid #a45b13;
    color: #381f00;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.ui-state-hover a, .ui-state-hover a:hover, .ui-state-hover a:link, .ui-state-hover a:visited, .ui-state-focus a, .ui-state-focus a:hover, .ui-state-focus a:link, .ui-state-focus a:visited {
    color: #381f00;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active {
    background: #ffffff url("/themeroller/images/ui-bg_inset-soft_30_ffffff_1x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50%;
    border: 1px solid #655e4e;
    color: #0074c7;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.ui-state-active a, .ui-state-active a:link, .ui-state-active a:visited {
    color: #0074c7;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
    background: #fff9e5 url("/themeroller/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_90_fff9e5_500x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% top;
    border: 1px solid #eeb420;
    color: #1f1f1f;
}
.ui-state-highlight a, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight a, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight a {
    color: #1f1f1f;
}
.ui-state-error, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error {
    background: #d34d17 url("/themeroller/images/ui-bg_diagonals-medium_20_d34d17_40x40.png") repeat scroll 50% 50%;
    border: 1px solid #ffb73d;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.ui-state-error a, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error a, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.ui-state-error-text, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error-text, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error-text {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.ui-priority-primary, .ui-widget-content .ui-priority-primary, .ui-widget-header .ui-priority-primary {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.ui-priority-secondary, .ui-widget-content .ui-priority-secondary, .ui-widget-header .ui-priority-secondary {
    font-weight: normal;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.ui-state-disabled, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-disabled, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-disabled {
    background-image: none;
    opacity: 0.35;
}
.ui-state-disabled .ui-icon {
}
.ui-icon {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
.ui-icon, .ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("/themeroller/images/ui-icons_d19405_256x240.png");
}
.ui-widget-header .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("/themeroller/images/ui-icons_fadc7a_256x240.png");
}
.ui-state-default .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("/themeroller/images/ui-icons_3d3d3d_256x240.png");
}
.ui-state-hover .ui-icon, .ui-state-focus .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("/themeroller/images/ui-icons_bd7b00_256x240.png");
}
.ui-state-active .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("/themeroller/images/ui-icons_eb990f_256x240.png");
}
.ui-state-highlight .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("/themeroller/images/ui-icons_ed9f26_256x240.png");
}
.ui-state-error .ui-icon, .ui-state-error-text .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("/themeroller/images/ui-icons_ffe180_256x240.png");
}
.ui-icon-blank {
    background-position: 16px 16px;
}
.ui-icon-carat-1-n {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.ui-icon-carat-1-ne {
    background-position: -16px 0;
}
.ui-icon-carat-1-e {
    background-position: -32px 0;
}
.ui-icon-carat-1-se {
    background-position: -48px 0;
}
.ui-icon-carat-1-s {
    background-position: -64px 0;
}
.ui-icon-carat-1-sw {
    background-position: -80px 0;
}
.ui-icon-carat-1-w {
    background-position: -96px 0;
}
.ui-icon-carat-1-nw {
    background-position: -112px 0;
}
.ui-icon-carat-2-n-s {
    background-position: -128px 0;
}
.ui-icon-carat-2-e-w {
    background-position: -144px 0;
}
.ui-icon-triangle-1-n {
    background-position: 0 -16px;
}
.ui-icon-triangle-1-ne {
    background-position: -16px -16px;
}
.ui-icon-triangle-1-e {
    background-position: -32px -16px;
}
.ui-icon-triangle-1-se {
    background-position: -48px -16px;
}
.ui-icon-triangle-1-s {
    background-position: -64px -16px;
}
.ui-icon-triangle-1-sw {
    background-position: -80px -16px;
}
.ui-icon-triangle-1-w {
    background-position: -96px -16px;
}
.ui-icon-triangle-1-nw {
    background-position: -112px -16px;
}
.ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s {
    background-position: -128px -16px;
}
.ui-icon-triangle-2-e-w {
    background-position: -144px -16px;
}
.ui-icon-arrow-1-n {
    background-position: 0 -32px;
}
.ui-icon-arrow-1-ne {
    background-position: -16px -32px;
}
.ui-icon-arrow-1-e {
    background-position: -32px -32px;
}
.ui-icon-arrow-1-se {
    background-position: -48px -32px;
}
.ui-icon-arrow-1-s {
    background-position: -64px -32px;
}
.ui-icon-arrow-1-sw {
    background-position: -80px -32px;
}
.ui-icon-arrow-1-w {
    background-position: -96px -32px;
}
.ui-icon-arrow-1-nw {
    background-position: -112px -32px;
}
.ui-icon-arrow-2-n-s {
    background-position: -128px -32px;
}
.ui-icon-arrow-2-ne-sw {
    background-position: -144px -32px;
}
.ui-icon-arrow-2-e-w {
    background-position: -160px -32px;
}
.ui-icon-arrow-2-se-nw {
    background-position: -176px -32px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowstop-1-n {
    background-position: -192px -32px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowstop-1-e {
    background-position: -208px -32px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowstop-1-s {
    background-position: -224px -32px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowstop-1-w {
    background-position: -240px -32px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n {
    background-position: 0 -48px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-ne {
    background-position: -16px -48px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e {
    background-position: -32px -48px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-se {
    background-position: -48px -48px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s {
    background-position: -64px -48px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-sw {
    background-position: -80px -48px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-w {
    background-position: -96px -48px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-nw {
    background-position: -112px -48px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s {
    background-position: -128px -48px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-ne-sw {
    background-position: -144px -48px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-e-w {
    background-position: -160px -48px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-se-nw {
    background-position: -176px -48px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-n {
    background-position: -192px -48px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-e {
    background-position: -208px -48px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s {
    background-position: -224px -48px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-w {
    background-position: -240px -48px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-w {
    background-position: 0 -64px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-n {
    background-position: -16px -64px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-e {
    background-position: -32px -64px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-s {
    background-position: -48px -64px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-w {
    background-position: -64px -64px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-n {
    background-position: -80px -64px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e {
    background-position: -96px -64px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-s {
    background-position: -112px -64px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w {
    background-position: -128px -64px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-n {
    background-position: -144px -64px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-e {
    background-position: -160px -64px;
}
.ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-s {
    background-position: -176px -64px;
}
.ui-icon-arrow-4 {
    background-position: 0 -80px;
}
.ui-icon-arrow-4-diag {
    background-position: -16px -80px;
}
.ui-icon-extlink {
    background-position: -32px -80px;
}
.ui-icon-newwin {
    background-position: -48px -80px;
}
.ui-icon-refresh {
    background-position: -64px -80px;
}
.ui-icon-shuffle {
    background-position: -80px -80px;
}
.ui-icon-transfer-e-w {
    background-position: -96px -80px;
}
.ui-icon-transferthick-e-w {
    background-position: -112px -80px;
}
.ui-icon-folder-collapsed {
    background-position: 0 -96px;
}
.ui-icon-folder-open {
    background-position: -16px -96px;
}
.ui-icon-document {
    background-position: -32px -96px;
}
.ui-icon-document-b {
    background-position: -48px -96px;
}
.ui-icon-note {
    background-position: -64px -96px;
}
.ui-icon-mail-closed {
    background-position: -80px -96px;
}
.ui-icon-mail-open {
    background-position: -96px -96px;
}
.ui-icon-suitcase {
    background-position: -112px -96px;
}
.ui-icon-comment {
    background-position: -128px -96px;
}
.ui-icon-person {
    background-position: -144px -96px;
}
.ui-icon-print {
    background-position: -160px -96px;
}
.ui-icon-trash {
    background-position: -176px -96px;
}
.ui-icon-locked {
    background-position: -192px -96px;
}
.ui-icon-unlocked {
    background-position: -208px -96px;
}
.ui-icon-bookmark {
    background-position: -224px -96px;
}
.ui-icon-tag {
    background-position: -240px -96px;
}
.ui-icon-home {
    background-position: 0 -112px;
}
.ui-icon-flag {
    background-position: -16px -112px;
}
.ui-icon-calendar {
    background-position: -32px -112px;
}
.ui-icon-cart {
    background-position: -48px -112px;
}
.ui-icon-pencil {
    background-position: -64px -112px;
}
.ui-icon-clock {
    background-position: -80px -112px;
}
.ui-icon-disk {
    background-position: -96px -112px;
}
.ui-icon-calculator {
    background-position: -112px -112px;
}
.ui-icon-zoomin {
    background-position: -128px -112px;
}
.ui-icon-zoomout {
    background-position: -144px -112px;
}
.ui-icon-search {
    background-position: -160px -112px;
}
.ui-icon-wrench {
    background-position: -176px -112px;
}
.ui-icon-gear {
    background-position: -192px -112px;
}
.ui-icon-heart {
    background-position: -208px -112px;
}
.ui-icon-star {
    background-position: -224px -112px;
}
.ui-icon-link {
    background-position: -240px -112px;
}
.ui-icon-cancel {
    background-position: 0 -128px;
}
.ui-icon-plus {
    background-position: -16px -128px;
}
.ui-icon-plusthick {
    background-position: -32px -128px;
}
.ui-icon-minus {
    background-position: -48px -128px;
}
.ui-icon-minusthick {
    background-position: -64px -128px;
}
.ui-icon-close {
    background-position: -80px -128px;
}
.ui-icon-closethick {
    background-position: -96px -128px;
}
.ui-icon-key {
    background-position: -112px -128px;
}
.ui-icon-lightbulb {
    background-position: -128px -128px;
}
.ui-icon-scissors {
    background-position: -144px -128px;
}
.ui-icon-clipboard {
    background-position: -160px -128px;
}
.ui-icon-copy {
    background-position: -176px -128px;
}
.ui-icon-contact {
    background-position: -192px -128px;
}
.ui-icon-image {
    background-position: -208px -128px;
}
.ui-icon-video {
    background-position: -224px -128px;
}
.ui-icon-script {
    background-position: -240px -128px;
}
.ui-icon-alert {
    background-position: 0 -144px;
}
.ui-icon-info {
    background-position: -16px -144px;
}
.ui-icon-notice {
    background-position: -32px -144px;
}
.ui-icon-help {
    background-position: -48px -144px;
}
.ui-icon-check {
    background-position: -64px -144px;
}
.ui-icon-bullet {
    background-position: -80px -144px;
}
.ui-icon-radio-on {
    background-position: -96px -144px;
}
.ui-icon-radio-off {
    background-position: -112px -144px;
}
.ui-icon-pin-w {
    background-position: -128px -144px;
}
.ui-icon-pin-s {
    background-position: -144px -144px;
}
.ui-icon-play {
    background-position: 0 -160px;
}
.ui-icon-pause {
    background-position: -16px -160px;
}
.ui-icon-seek-next {
    background-position: -32px -160px;
}
.ui-icon-seek-prev {
    background-position: -48px -160px;
}
.ui-icon-seek-end {
    background-position: -64px -160px;
}
.ui-icon-seek-start {
    background-position: -80px -160px;
}
.ui-icon-seek-first {
    background-position: -80px -160px;
}
.ui-icon-stop {
    background-position: -96px -160px;
}
.ui-icon-eject {
    background-position: -112px -160px;
}
.ui-icon-volume-off {
    background-position: -128px -160px;
}
.ui-icon-volume-on {
    background-position: -144px -160px;
}
.ui-icon-power {
    background-position: 0 -176px;
}
.ui-icon-signal-diag {
    background-position: -16px -176px;
}
.ui-icon-signal {
    background-position: -32px -176px;
}
.ui-icon-battery-0 {
    background-position: -48px -176px;
}
.ui-icon-battery-1 {
    background-position: -64px -176px;
}
.ui-icon-battery-2 {
    background-position: -80px -176px;
}
.ui-icon-battery-3 {
    background-position: -96px -176px;
}
.ui-icon-circle-plus {
    background-position: 0 -192px;
}
.ui-icon-circle-minus {
    background-position: -16px -192px;
}
.ui-icon-circle-close {
    background-position: -32px -192px;
}
.ui-icon-circle-triangle-e {
    background-position: -48px -192px;
}
.ui-icon-circle-triangle-s {
    background-position: -64px -192px;
}
.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w {
    background-position: -80px -192px;
}
.ui-icon-circle-triangle-n {
    background-position: -96px -192px;
}
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-e {
    background-position: -112px -192px;
}
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-s {
    background-position: -128px -192px;
}
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-w {
    background-position: -144px -192px;
}
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-n {
    background-position: -160px -192px;
}
.ui-icon-circle-zoomin {
    background-position: -176px -192px;
}
.ui-icon-circle-zoomout {
    background-position: -192px -192px;
}
.ui-icon-circle-check {
    background-position: -208px -192px;
}
.ui-icon-circlesmall-plus {
    background-position: 0 -208px;
}
.ui-icon-circlesmall-minus {
    background-position: -16px -208px;
}
.ui-icon-circlesmall-close {
    background-position: -32px -208px;
}
.ui-icon-squaresmall-plus {
    background-position: -48px -208px;
}
.ui-icon-squaresmall-minus {
    background-position: -64px -208px;
}
.ui-icon-squaresmall-close {
    background-position: -80px -208px;
}
.ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical {
    background-position: 0 -224px;
}
.ui-icon-grip-dotted-horizontal {
    background-position: -16px -224px;
}
.ui-icon-grip-solid-vertical {
    background-position: -32px -224px;
}
.ui-icon-grip-solid-horizontal {
    background-position: -48px -224px;
}
.ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se {
    background-position: -64px -224px;
}
.ui-icon-grip-diagonal-se {
    background-position: -80px -224px;
}
.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-top, .ui-corner-left, .ui-corner-tl {
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
}
.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-top, .ui-corner-right, .ui-corner-tr {
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}
.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-bottom, .ui-corner-left, .ui-corner-bl {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}
.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-bottom, .ui-corner-right, .ui-corner-br {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}
.ui-widget-overlay {
    background: #5c5c5c url("/themeroller/images/ui-bg_flat_50_5c5c5c_40x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50%;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.ui-widget-shadow {
    background: #cccccc url("/themeroller/images/ui-bg_flat_30_cccccc_40x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin: -7px 0 0 -7px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    padding: 7px;
}

  </style>

<!-- Datepicker -->
<div class="demo"><p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p></div>
```

Comment: This answer is nothing more than the demo that is provide with jQuery UI.

Comment: can you provide demo for Datepicker not displaying the theme correctly

Comment: Take a look at this demo: [http://jsfiddle.net/4y3zehf0/](http://jsfiddle.net/4y3zehf0/)  I added in the styles.css that is currently getting used with the project.  Just click on the input field.

Comment: here is demo http://jsfiddle.net/rock2012/oa3mwm13/  there is css missing or background image path issue